# How to add multiple words as one expression in OpenOffice dictionary

Tags: spell-check, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

I'm writing a German text on open source. I'd like to set the OpenOffice spell checker to the following behavior: Accept "Open Source" (with capital letters) as a correct word, but highlight any other combination of "open" and "source" (regardless of capitalization). Is that possible and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this isn't possible solely on the level of spell checking. But you can solve this issue **using different language settings for your text**: you could define a new AutoText entry with the text "Open Source" and language set to English (USA). If the language for those two words is set to English, spell checking will accept it as correct. And AutoText may contain custom character style settings like different language settings.

So, you could proceed as follows:

1. In your document, enter and select the text "Open Source";
2. Right-click on selection, select "`Character`"; on the "`Font`" tab, select "`English (USA)`" as language for those two words; click <kbd>OK</kbd>;
3. While the two words are still selected, open menu "`Edit`" -> "`AutoText`" or hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>;
4. Optionally, select the category;
5. Enter a describing name and a shortcut (for example `OpS`);
6. Hit button <kbd>AutoText</kbd> and select entry "`New`" (**don't** select "`New (text only)`", since this will strip the language setting from the new AutoText entry).
7. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Now, if you enter `OpS`in your German text and hit <kbd>F3</kbd>, OpenOffice will replace it by "`Open Source`" with language set to english, so spell checking will accept it.

*Note: I've tested this with LibreOffice Writer, but i'm sure it works with OpenOffice.org Writer, too.*